# Scipy Minimization Problem, how to find the global minima when there is multiple local minima

Tags: python, scipy

I have a function with 2 adjustable variables g(x,y) that I am minimizing to fit function f(a,b) with bounds 0 to inf.

This is done using the basic

```
bnds=np.array([0,np.inf])
minimize(min_fun,args=(funx_output), x0=[0,0], bounds=bnds,method='L-BFGS-B')
```

The problem isn't the code or setup, but the chi2 landscape for this g(x,y).

[image]

This is a contour map showing the chi2 between 1.25 and 1.3. I am trying to determine exactly where the global minima is, but as you can see, there are multiple minima (these are all within 0.0000001 of one another, so very similar), but a global minima does exist (if I run a minimization with a grid search of different starting conditions, I get different outputs). I don't know exactly why this type of oscilatting chi2 exists.

Does anyone know why my function would behave this way? Or what kind of minimization method would help in finding the global minima in a situation like this?

Comment: Only you know why `min_fun` behaves in that way, it's hard to know why the function is so oscillatory without knowing what it is. `L-BFGS-B` is not suited for finding global minima. I suggest using the global minimisers from [`scipy.optimize`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html#global-optimization).

Comment: @AndrewNelson I understand. Any idea what the fastest/best optimization technique would be for a situation like mine (with multiple local minima spread across a wide range of values)?

Comment: Try using differential_evolution